# AngularJS 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I've this problem, when I click on login button, the chrome console log this:

> angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at m.$scope.logIn (loginModuleController.js:11)

Service:

```
angular.module('loginModule')
.factory('loginService', function($http){
  return{
    login: function(username, password){
      var session;
      $http.post('../server/php/auth/auth.php', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(function(res){
        session = res;
      });
      return session;
    },
    isLogged: function(){
      return $http.get('../angCMS/server/php/auth.php?is_logged=true');
    },
    logOut: function(){
      return $http.get('../angCMS/server/php/auth.php?logout=true');
    }
  };
});
```

controller:

```
angular.module('loginModule')
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'loginService', function($scope, loginService){

  $scope.auth = false;

  $scope.username;
  $scope.password;
  $scope.logIn = function(){
    loginService.login($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function(response){

    }, function(res){

    });
  };

  $scope.isLogged = function(){
    loginService.isLogged()
    .then(function(response){
      if(response){
        $scope.auth = true;
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.logOut = function(){
    loginService.logOut()
    .then(function(response){
      if(response){
        $scope.auth = false;
      }
    });
  };

}]);
```

and this is the html template:

```
<div class="container" ng-if="auth==false">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="row">
      <br/><h2 align="center">Login</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="logIn()">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP login method:

```
public function login($user, $pass){

        $user = htmlspecialchars(trim($user));
        $pass = md5(htmlspecialchars(trim($pass)));

        $res = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE username = :user");
        if(!$res->execute(Array(":user"=>$user)))
            die(mysql_error());

        $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!$row['password'] == $pass)
            die("Errore: password errata!");

        $_SESSION['logged'] = $row;
        array_push($session, $_SESSION['logged'], true);

        return $session;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a misuse of promises issue.

You might want to first take a look of how promises work:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

From your service code:

```
login: function(username, password){
  var session;
  $http.post('../server/php/auth/auth.php', {
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
  .then(function(res){
    session = res;
  });
  return session;
}
```

When `login(username, password)` is called, session is still `undefined` upon returning.

This is because `$http.post()` is an asynchronous function, the `.then()` clause does not get executed immediately.

As pointed out by [Snixtor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955434/angularjs-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined/37957186#37955510),
you should "return the return value of `$http.post()`":

```
login: function(username, password){
  return $http.post('../server/php/auth/auth.php', {
    username: username,
    password: password
  });
}
```

Then referring to your controller's logIn method:

```
$scope.logIn = function(){
  loginService.login($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function(response){
    // response === 'session' 
  }, function(res){

  });
};
```

the `response` parameter from `loginService.login().then()` is exactly the value of your intended `session` variable from your previous implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You're returning an unassigned variable named "session".  So what you are doing here in your logged in method is returning undefined.  Undefined does not have a method called then.

```
login: function(username, password){
      var session;
      $http.post('../server/php/auth/auth.php', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(function(res){
        session = res;
      });
      return session;
    },
```

My guess is you actually want to return the $http.post method, which in turn returns a promise.  That way you can use the session in the controller?

Comment: I just added the php  login method

Comment: The php is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Your service function `login` is failing to return the promise created by the call to `$http.post`. Instead, you need this:

```
login: function(username, password){
  return $http.post('../server/php/auth/auth.php', {
    username: username,
    password: password
  });
}
```

Note too that I've removed the `session` variable from the function. It's the `then` function in your controller that needs to be dealing with the response.

Your `isLogged` and `logOut` functions look good already. Just repeat that pattern.

Comment: I just added the php  login method

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the php method. Do you understand what I've said in the answer?

Comment: I realized it , I put the php just to let you see what I wanted to come back from the method