# Angular - Having troubles receiving $http response from a factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-factory

I have an `angular` `factory` doing some `$http` communication to the server and returning a string. However I get the `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955434/angularjs-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined) with similar problems however I was not able to resolve my problem.

This is the service code:

```
factory("availabilityService", ['$http', function ($http) {

    return {
        checkAvailability1: function (element, string) {
           // ..... some object creation code ......
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'server/server.php',
                data: AvailableObj,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    return response;

                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Inside a `controller`:

```
$scope.checkAvailability = function (element, string) {
   availabilityService.checkAvailability1(element, string).then(function (response) { //on this line the error occurs 
       console.log(response);

   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the promise returned by `$http` i.e add a 'return' in front of $http to get your code working like below :

```
return $http(...)
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });
```

This is because, the function you have called from the controller should have a `.then` method on it i.e it should be a promise. `checkAvailability1` in angular returns a promise which needs to be returned back by your function `$http` in the factory. You are just returning the response from the success callback which is not expected by your method in the controller.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this? I already returned the object itself and the response of the http request.

Comment: @undroid You are returning that response from the _callback method_, not from the function that actually made the $http request (checkAvailability1). That result never goes anywhere outside the scope of checkAvailability1. Return statements do not implicitly "bubble up" through the call stack.